# IIS Redirect a sub directory to an external URL

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, proxy, reverse-proxy

Hi forgive my ignorance for I am a humble client side developer...

I am a webapp made up of static HTML and JS.  But I want to call an external service via AJAX, this causes some issues with CORS or Cross Domain policy on the browser.

So I need to make a request to MY server http://dev.webapp.com**/service**

So I want to redirect the **/service** on the server to **http://externaldata.com/service**

And return the result.

The Mac boys have acheived this in Apache with a proxy pass:

```
ProxyPass /service http://externaldata.com/service
```

Can anybody help with how to do this in IIS?

I have found articles about ARRs and Reverse Proxy, terms that are alien and seem too complicated.  As a humble webdev can I do this using IIS GUI?

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly straightforward example of what you are trying to accomplish here: http://www.nathanfox.net/blog/4/Cross-domain-AJAX-call-using-IIS-7-and-Microsoft-URL-Rewrite